# help me understand a variable setting

Tags: javascript

```
var fmt = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var cls = (fmt<=240)?'pda_ver':(fmt>240&&fmt<=320)?'pda_hor':(fmt>320&&fmt<=640)?'screen_ultralow':(fmt>640&&fmt<=800)?'screen_low':(fmt>800&&fmt<=1024)?'screen_med':(fmt>1024&&fmt<=1280)?'screen_high':'screen_wide';
```

can someone tell me what this does (just the part where the variable is set with a value. I do not understand... what are the `?`, `:` have for a role here)? i have never seen a variable declared like that. Is this a conditional variable setting? if yes how does it work ?

[working example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/switchymclayout/transition_layout_tab.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a horrible example of abuse of the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Obj-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript).

Using a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch) would look much nicer.

Comment: If you ever have more than 1 ? in a line of code, think about it some more ;)

Comment: what is horrible about this example?

Comment: @meo: The fact that you, among other people, can't immediately read it.

Comment: @meo It's a very nested use and consequently very difficult to read.

Comment: but is there a practical reason to do this beside writing less code? is it faster then the classical if statement somehow?

Comment: @meo no, it's just convenient sometimes. But easy to abuse

Answer (score 4):

This construction is somewhat common in languages:

```
statement3 ? statement2 : statement1
```

It is used to inline a conditional, and it reads:

```
if (statement3) {
  statement2;
} else {
  statement1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand of:

```
var cls;
if (fmt <= 240) {
  cls = 'pda_ver';
} else {
 if (fmt > 240 && fmt <= 320) {
   cls = 'pda_hor';
 } else {
 ....
```

and so on

Comment: "Shorthand" is arguable... I'd choose if/ else over that mess any day :)